# Sending ajax post request, but $_POST in PHP is always empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem sending data with an AJAX query to a php file, basically I use post request to send some data just for testing it out, the request is successful when I checked with developer tools in Chrome, as I can see the data that was sent , but the variable `$_POST[]` in php is always null, and don't understand why, because my data was sent to the php file.

Tried all kind of possibilities found on here, non of them will let me to go further, all of them will leave my `$_POST[]` empty. I modified the values inside the data attribute I added or removed content-type but nothing worked.

Here you have my jQuery code.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "2.php",
  data: { name: 'JohnDoe', age: '19' }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert(msg);
});
```

This is my PHP code.

```
<?php

$user=$_POST['name'];
 var_dump($user); 
?>
```

**Errors**

```
$user=$_POST['name'];

//ERROR - Notice: Undefined index: name in G:\xampp\htdocs\weather\2.php on line 6
//Expected result is 'JohnDoe'.
```

```
 var_dump($user); 

//this is Null 
//Expected result is to contain some data
```

This are my two results I get in php.

The html and php files are in the same folder.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and tested it. It works fine — https://i.imgur.com/KsiiOLH.png  — whatever the problem is, it isn't with the code you shared with us. Voting to close because "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest **code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself."

Comment: Data is returned but not passed in the php seems to be, because when I access my php file I get the following errors,
Notice: Undefined index: name in G:\xampp\htdocs\weather\2.php on line 9
NULL
Please try to access the php file and see if you get any errors

Comment: "when I access my php file I get the following errors" — **How** are you trying to access it?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/weather/2.php, by the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two HTTP requests.

The first one using JavaScript, where you make a POST request and alert the response.

You can see the data from the response there. [image: screenshot]

You make the second request by typing the address into the address bar, where you make a GET request and have the response rendered as a webpage.

---

`$_POST` contains the POSTed data from the **current** request, not the data from any previous request.

The data you POSTed when you made the first request is not available when the PHP program runs again using the second request as input.

If you want to access that data then you need to **explicitly** do something to make it persist. This could be linked to the browser (so different users would not see each others data) — such as in a session or a cookie — or it could be independent of the browser — such as in a database — so every visitor to the site could see the data.

Comment: Lost an entire day to understand how data have been returned from php to your html file, basically what I was doing, I was accessing by url in my local server the php file where there is inside a $_POST[] method and expecting to see the data which is returning, but what's happening when you request a file from a server you use get method to request the file, and I wanted to return values which are in the post method requested by my $.ajax() call in my html file, you have to understand that you should expect the data back in the html file not by accessing your php file, thank you again Quentin